# format method in NumberFormat Java

Tags: java, text, io, number-formatting

Does anybody know any real use of [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#format%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.text.FieldPosition%29) method?

> format
>
> public StringBuffer format(Object number,
>                     StringBuffer toAppendTo,
>                     FieldPosition pos)
>
> Formats a number and appends the resulting text to the given string
>   buffer. The number can be of any subclass of Number.

how does the `StringBuffer` interact with `FieldPosition` (Integer/Fractional).

In short, a real life code example would be very useful.

Comment: Why don't you try it, see what you get and post the answer? Since there is no `StringBuilder` version of this seems fairly legacy. Given the entire javadoc seems straightforward. Format value, insert it into the buffer at the desired location and return updated buffer and location information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formats a long value and prints out the beginning and ending indices of the integer part of the long:

```
    // Get a default NumberFormat instance.
    NumberFormat numForm = NumberFormat.getInstance();

    // Format some longs using the pattern supplied above.
    StringBuffer dest1 = new StringBuffer(24);
    StringBuffer dest2 = new StringBuffer(24);
    FieldPosition pos = new FieldPosition(NumberFormat.INTEGER_FIELD);

    dest1 = numForm.format(223423L, dest1, pos);
    System.out.println("dest1 = " + dest1);
    System.out.println("INTEGER portion is at: " + pos.getBeginIndex() +
        ", " + pos.getEndIndex());

    dest2 = numForm.format(64000L, dest2, pos);
    System.out.println("dest2 = " + dest2);
    System.out.println("INTEGER portion is at: " + pos.getBeginIndex() +
        ", " + pos.getEndIndex());
```

Output:

dest1 = 223,423

INTEGER portion is at: 0, 7

dest2 = 64,000

INTEGER portion is at: 0, 6

Comment: Nice example but would be more interesting if buffer already had text and position provided insert location.